# AngularJS service/factory dynamically $compile HTML from $scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Attempting to consolidate a function used across multiple controllers in an AngularJS project to a service/factory that I can call using `$rootScope`. The goal is to change the following function:

```
$scope.twitterRefresh = function(obj) {
      try { 
          var old = document.getElementById('twitterContainer');
          old.parentNode.removeChild(old);
      }
      catch (err) {};
      var html = "<div id='twitterContainer'>"+$scope.game[0]['twitterEmbed']+"</div>";
    var elem = $compile(html)($scope);
    angular.element(document.getElementById('twitterEmbed')).append(elem);
};
```

into a combination of a `$rootScope` & `service` to avoid having to include the service in every controller that requires the function. The following code, however, isn't working:

```
app.factory('twitterRefresh', ['$document', '$compile', '$rootScope',
    function(obj,$document, $compile, $rootScope) {
  try { 
      var old = document.getElementById('twitterContainer');
      old.parentNode.removeChild(old);
  }
  catch (err) {};
  var html = "<div id='twitterContainer'>"+obj+"</div>";
  var scope = $rootScope.$new();
  var elem = $compile(html)(scope);
  angular.element(document.getElementById('twitterEmbed')).append(elem);
}]);

app.run(function($rootScope, twitterRefresh) {
    $rootScope.twitterRefresh= function(obj){
      twitterRefresh(obj);
    }
});
```

where the following function is called in the controller..

```
   $scope.twitterRefresh = $rootScope.twitterRefresh($scope.game[0]['twitterEmbed']);
```

Comment: `$scope.twitterRefresh() = $rootScope.twitterRefresh...`. did you mean to put the brackets `()` in? `$scope.twitterRefresh = function() { $rootScope.twitterRefresh($scope.game[0]['twitterEmbed']); }` looks more useful to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't define the function on each controller $scope, just leave it on $rootScope, and use it when needed elsewhere by injecting $rootScope into your controller and making it available that way.

```
   //something like this

   app.run(function($rootScope, $compile) {
       $rootScope.twitterRefresh= function(obj, scope){
           $compile(obj)(scope);
       }
   });
```

Comment: i believe the question I have is how to pass the variable `$scope.game[0]['twitterEmbed']` to either the service/factory or the rootScope function

Comment: secondly, how should a $rootScope function correctly call the $compile service

Comment: To correctly call $compile you would need to pass the $scope instance to the $rootScope function you have defined. If your $rootScope function is in app.js run function, make sure you inject $compile service, and pass the $scope instance from the controller. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
app.factory('twitterRefresh', ['$document', '$compile', '$rootScope',
  function($document, $compile, $rootScope) {
    return function (obj) {
      try { 
        var old = document.getElementById('twitterContainer');
        old.parentNode.removeChild(old);
      }
      catch (err) {};
      var html = "<div id='twitterContainer'>"+obj+"</div>";
      var scope = $rootScope.$new();
      var elem = $compile(html)(scope);
      angular.element(document.getElementById('twitterEmbed')).append(elem);
    }
  }
]);
```